# PHP hand variable to another php document

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to get a variable which I declared in one php file to another without including the whole first php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    // Urlaubstage ausgeben
    if($row['frtutage'] < 1) {
        $verbraucht = "0";
    } else {
        $verbraucht = $row['frtutage'];
    }
    $resturlaub = $row['miturlaubstage'] + $row['mitutagevorjahr'] - $verbraucht;
    $urlaubgesamt = $row['miturlaubstage'] + $row['mitutagevorjahr'];
```

I need the variable `$resturlaub` in the second PHP without calculating the variable again. 
How do I do this? Or is it even possible?

Thanks.

edit: the first php file is about calculating vacation days and how much I have remaind after taking a few vacation days, in the second file I need the calculation of the remaining days then, so I just want to use the variable again and not calculate it again

Comment: What is the relationship between the two PHP files?

Comment: if on the same server, you can setup a session or a cookie to share these variables.

Comment: Until the op provides the relationship between the files as @Quentin suggested, there is not really much assistance that can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try somehting like

```
$var = 'random_query';
$page= 'yourpage.com/?my_var='.serialize($var);
header("Location: $page");
exit;
```

and in your page you can get the value by

```
if (isset($_GET['my_var']))
{
     $my_var = unserialize($_GET['my_var']);
}
```

But it would depend on the size of that variable that you need to pass, and what is the purpose of the scripts.

Comment: the size of the variable is a double digit integer, the purpose of the first php script is to calculate the vacation days of all employee in my company, how many they have annual and how many they have used for that year and how many remaining days they have. the second script is about showing in a list how many days they have for the next year if they spent to many in the current year. 
So in summary I just need to put the variable    `$resturlaub` in the new list, but how without calculating ?

Comment: why not put both scripts in the same file? or a copy of the first in the second if you need them separately? In this case, using Classes and extending one another would be the best choice...my opinion

Comment: this script will redirect you to your other script with the variable set as a query string in the URL

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include the whole first php file but only a variable then you should create a third file (called: variables.php or config.php for example).

Then include variables.php in both file so the variable will be shared among your scripts

Comment: okay, but in the first file im calculating the variable I need, how could I declare the Variable without calculating it ? isn't there a possibility to use like    `$_POST` to get the variable to the second php file ? :S

Comment: just declare it with a default value and then you can use it everywhere (make sure to include the file in the top part of the two others).